# How to get Wordpress TwentyTwelve comments.php to work on another theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

Currently, I'm using a Wordpress theme that is built on [Foundation](https://github.com/drewsymo/Foundation). However, the theme doesn't have its own `comment.php` file and it's currently using the soon to be deprecated `comments.php` from `wordpress\wp-includes\theme-compat` folder.

So what I did is to copy/paste the latest `comments.php` file from the TwentyTwelve theme folder into my current theme folder. However, this results in an error:

```
Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'twentytwelve_comment' not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\comment-template.php on line 1334
```

...since it's not properly wired up. What should I do to get the `comments.php` to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TwentyTwelve uses a function of its own to format comments-- [`twentytwelve_comment`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/functions.php#L269). In the file you copied-- `comments.php`-- you should see this line:

```
<?php wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentytwelve_comment', 'style' => 'ol' ) ); ?>
```

That callback is to a function that doesn't exist in your theme, since it is defined in TwentyTwelve's `functions.php` and not yours. You can...

- Remove the callback-- this part `'callback' => 'twentytwelve_comment',`. It is optional.  WordPress will use a default formatting function-- [actually a `method` of the `Walker_comment` class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1328). Its a bit hard to find. :)
- Copy TwentyTwelve's callback function to your theme; don't do anything to disguise where you got it
- Create your own callback